# Biber destroys my document?

Tags: biblatex, errors, biber, undefined, generic

I am finishing right now my senior thesis in Latex. Everything went fine when I did use natbib and BibTex. Then I decided to switch to BibLatex with Biber. Unfortunately, my compiler doesn't deliver any bibliography anymore. The log states as well "Empty bibliography", "There were undefined references." and finally "Please (re)run Biber on the file:(biblatex) Thesis(biblatex) and rerun LaTeX afterwards."

In order to adress this issue, I decided to run biber manually in the console. Biber successfully runs through. But now I have very serious problems. After manually starting biber, I get several errors when compiling the Tex file. Mostly "Undefined commmands" or "Generic errors". I get them with several parts. I get them when using "\begin{enumerate}" or when using "\include{intro}" for including my chapters from distinct tex files.
As soon as I delete all created temp files (except the bib and tex files), I can recreate all steps I did just describe. I seem to believe the error lies within biber. Is there any way to use sth else than biber as backend when using biblatex? This error did cost me now some hours and I have no clue how to solve/adress it...

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: It's close to impossible to help you with the given information. Please have a look at https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407. In addition, here's a tutorial that may help you: https://youtu.be/ZYvS52511oQ. In general, it's almost never a good idea to change the "system" when you are close to a deadline if you cannot test it risk-free (e. g. virtual machine, overleaf, friend's PC, ...).

Comment: Danke für deine Antwort! Durch das Erstellen eines Minimalbeispiels ist mir aufgefallen, dass dies funktioniert und im Aufblähen der Datei entdecke ich ja wo der Fehler liegt. Wenn ich den Fehler doch nicht lösen kann, dann gibt es hier auch ein richtiges Beispiel ;)

Comment: I'd try deleting the `.aux` files of the document and recompile.

Comment: That's what I meant by "delete all created temp files".

Comment: +1: That's the beauty of creating an MWE! :)

Comment: you need to at the very least show the _exact_ error that you got in the log file add as a code block in your question the full error from `!` to `?` Preferably also a complete small test document.

Comment: Should we close this question and you open a new question when you figured out a minimal working example?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP apparently managed to find the error while they were preparing an MWE. It is almost impossible to diagnose the problem from the question as it stands now, so this question is unlikely to help future visitors.